# why doesn't jsdelvr take my latest npm package

Tags: npm, cdn, jsdelivr

I have made an npm package called [awesome-react-gamepads](https://www.npmjs.com/package/awesome-react-gamepads) and updated the version several times (currently 0.1.2). This is fine and if you use npm you get the latest version however cdn's like jsdelvr do not have even close to the latest version as seen here https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/awesome-react-gamepads. Is there something I have to specify in my config to force this? I can provide more code upon request I just don't know where the issue is. In my package.json I have the following scripts:

```
 "scripts": {
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"src/**/*.js\"",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json",
    "test": "jest --config jestconfig.json",
    "compile": "tsc -p tsconfig.json && tsc -p tsconfig-cjs.json && tsc -p tsconfig-umd.json",
    "prepublish": "npm run compile"
  },
```